# Windows 7 Find Who Accesses a Shared Folder

Tags: windows-7, logging, shared-folders

could anyone help me in finding the access logs to a shared folder in Windows 7.

I would like to get information like the user name, time, IP, etc.

I have already looked into the Event Viewer to find nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up the audit log for that
go to group policy editor and open audit object access and check both options
than you need to open the properties of the shared folder and configure the audit
after that you can view the logs on event viewer

[See a explained tutorial here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/123362-audit-log-access-shared-folders.html)